# FreeBSD equivalent for Linux configuration of OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, freebsd

I'm following a tutorial (https://snikt.net/blog/2016/12/01/openvpn-over-https/) regarding OpenVPN via SSL on Linux machines.
At one point it states:

> We modify /etc/default/openvpn to automatically enable this tunnel
>   when Openvpn starts:
>
> AUTOSTART="ssl"

Can anyone tell me what the equivalent of this on FreeBSD 11 is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the next lines to the `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
openvpn_enable="YES" 
openvpn_if="tun" 
openvpn_configfile="/usr/local/etc/openvpn/server.conf"
openvpn_dir="/usr/local/etc/openvpn"
```

Then you have to start the service:

```
service openvpn start
```

If you want to restart service after some edits make to the config, you have to run

```
service openvpn restart
```

Comment: This I did and everything works. I'm just wondering if my traffic now really is going over HTTPS in order to obscure the usage of OpenVPN, pretending to just use SSL via HTTPS.

Comment: Apache and nginx `httpd` do not need `openvpn` to establish https connections, they have all functionality bundled already

Comment: You can also monitor the traffic with `tcpdump -v -i <netinterface>` to verify your settings.